# apache .htaccess file https:// redirect ---- rewrite it for subdirectory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This will successfully rewrite everything to https (it will "force" https), if I put it in my home directory's .htaccess file. However, what about if I only want my subdirectory of /support to force https? How to rewrite the above code?

The intent is with regards to forcing https in WHMCS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: subdomain support means? `http://subdomain.sitename.com/` to `https://subdomain.sitename.com/` and not redirect from `http://sitename.com` to `https://sitename.com` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following rule before the %{HTTPS} line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^support.domain.com$
```

This will only allow the rule to execute if the visitor is coming from the subdomain. Please note, these rules will likely need to be put in the .htaccess file that is the root for the subdomain, not the main site root folder.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant subdirectory, not subdomain. Thanks

Comment: thanks! Only thing is i asked the wrong question I think, because I am looking for a subdirectory, not a subdomain (_site.com/subdirectory_ vs _subdomain.site.com_)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect only a subfolder and not a subdomain, that is even easier. To redirect the subfolder /support/ you would use the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/support/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/support/$1 [QSA]
```

I added a QSA flag, which will force any query string that was entered to be appended to the redirect URL. If you don't use query strings in this section of the site, you can remove that flag. Also, if the string as shown doesn't work, you can try removing the leading slash from the RewriteRule and retrying it.